# USB bootable not detecting

Tags: system-installation, bios, usb-installation

There is a laptop (DELL G15). I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 instead of windows from bootable USB but I couldn't detect the OS [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: 1. Please tell us how you made (what tool/method you used to make) the USB drive bootable with Ubuntu; 2. Please tell us also the point release (x in 22.04.x LTS) of the iso file; 3. Try to turn off 'all extra locks' for example TPM and Secure Boot. (It should be OK to boot in UEFI mode, but easier without the extra locks.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image attached, you have the laptop set to UEFI boot only.

Depending on how you have created the usb, it may only be legacy bootable and not UEFI, therefore the "bios" will not detect it as bootable.

In the BIOS setup screen, use the arrow keys to navigate to the "Boot" tab and press Enter.

In the "Boot" tab, you will see a "Boot Mode" or "Boot List Option" setting. Use the arrow keys to select it and press Enter.

In the "Boot Mode" or "Boot List Option" setting, select "Legacy Support" and press Enter.

Then reboot, press F12 at the startup to bring up the "one time boot" menu, and you should be able to select the USB drive.

Comment: thanks for helping but i searched for Legacy Support and didn't find it

Comment: If you are using windows download rufus from https://rufus.ie/en/ and redo the USB drive as UEFI.  You need select "BIOS or UEFI" or select "GPT" in Partition Scheme, and "UEFI (non CSM)" in the target system box.  This will make the usb drive, bootable by your laptop.

Comment: My 11th Gen Intel based Dell is UEFI only. And new systems are UEFI (since 2012), but older UEFI systems may have UEFI or BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode also which you do not want. You need to be sure to create installer in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: @oldfred, I checked the laptop manual before I suggested the legacy boot option, I am assuming they have removed the option when they updated the firmware of the laptop

Comment: It is possible that the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS iso file is too old for the new computer. I suggest that you try with Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 instead. It has a newer boot system with keys, that can handle newer locks that the computer manufacturers have implemented in cooperation with Microsoft.

Comment: When booted, you may run into problems with the nvidia graphics card. If that happens, please try with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`.

Comment: If 22.04 latest, it should work. Not sure what video that system has, but my Dell laptop with 11th Gen Intel just worked with 22.04 original release of Kubuntu. Newer version may have newer updates that do work better.

Comment: The ISO file makes not difference if it is UEFI or legacy, all the matters is how the ISO is written to the USB device.  If the USB has been setup as a block device, and not a ISO device, then you could easily add a efi partition, and copy the boot files.  refind is a good package that allows multi boot. Another tool that is worth mentioning is ventoy https://www.ventoy.net this formats a usb drive for uefi booting, and allows for chain booting iso's that are stored on the usb drive.